# EPR related question

Tags: quantum-mechanics, quantum-entanglement, double-slit-experiment, epr-experiment

Suppose two entangled electrons are emitted from a source. After traveling a long distance in opposite directions, each electron passes through separate but otherwise identical double slits. Will both electrons be detected in precisely the same location relative to the center of the double slit apparatus?  Let me edit this question - and ask it with an entangled electron and positron pair, or, if you prefer, a photon pair. Same question though, after passing through identical but separated double slit apparatuses, is each particle (or photon) measured at the same position relative to the center of each apparatus?

Comment: Is the source like an electron-gun which fires in opposite directions at the same time?

Comment: I hope the edit above clarifies the previous formulation of the question. My apologies.

Comment: Suppose a man walks down a street.  Which way will he turn when he gets to the corner?  Does it seem to you that more information is needed?  Does it seem to you  that "the man is walking fast" is not the kind of information that's going to be helpful here?  How can we possibly know what your electron will do if we don't know the initial state of the system?  Telling us that it's entangled is about as informative as telling us that the man is walking fast.

Comment: WillO, Thanks, that was helpful. I had the wrong idea that entangled meant all measurables would be correlated. Can you tell me, say for electron-positron entanglements, which measurables of these particles can be correlated?

Answer (score 1):

Welcome!

No. The only properties that stay entangled are the electron's spins. If you measure the position of one electron then this has no influence on where the other electron will be found. The wavefunctions don't overlap anymore at such great distances. The spins in the spin part of the total wavefunction stay connected by a "spooky" interaction contrary to the space part.

Comment: Descheleshilder, thank you.

Comment: Always welcome!